# Reverse iteration from a given map iterator

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I want to find an element in the map using `map::find(key)`, and then iterate the map in reverse order from the point where I found the element, till the beginning (i.e. until  `map::rend()`).

However, I get a compile error when I try to assign my iterator to a reverse_iterator.  How do I solve this?

Comment: In the future, a small code snippet and the exact error message from the compiler can greatly help solve most questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Converting an iterator to a reverse iterator via the constructor should work fine, e.g. `std::map<K, V>::reverse_iterator rit(mypos)`.

A minimal example using std::vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  typedef std::vector<int> intVec;
  intVec vec;
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) vec.push_back(i);

  for(intVec::reverse_iterator it(std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 10));
      it != vec.rend(); it++)
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: +1. Note that the key part of this answer is replacing `it = ..` with `it (..)`, so that the explicit ctor can be used.

Comment: Thanks Rodger, it is indeed one of the constructors of reverse_iterator and _not_ the copy constructor. My bad.

Comment: Why is the result `9876543210`, not `109876543210`?

Answer (score 5):

Make the conversion explicit:

```
std::map<int, int> SomeMap;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    SomeMap[ i ] = i;

std::map<int, int>::iterator it = SomeMap.find( 5 );
std::map<int, int>::reverse_iterator itr( it );

for ( itr; itr != SomeMap.rend( ); itr++ )
    std::cout << itr->first << std::endl;
```

Comment: At the first iteration, could you explain why the `itr` points to 4, not 5? The `it` points to 5 before conversion.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, this has been ages ago :) But from what I remember, `reverse_iterator` shifts the element pointed to by 1. This is done to make sure that, when creating a reverse iterator from the past-the-end iterator of a range, it points to the last value in that range.